# Azure Suggestions API text with - in middle of text like (HF - heart failure)

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I am using Azure Suggestions (auto-complete) API

This API working fine for search by keywords

but there is a case like a keyword "HF - Heart failure" try to search

[image]

I am getting a result but not in short order means it should show this on the first choice but it comes the third choice I think it may be - in middle of a word

```
 SuggestParameters suggestParameters = new SuggestParameters()
            {
                UseFuzzyMatching = fuzzy,
                Top = 8,
                SearchFields = new List<string>
                 {
                     "Keyword"
                 }
            };
            return _titleIndexClient.Documents.Suggest(searchText, "sgt", suggestParameters);}
```

Answer (score 2):

The API that you are using from the SDK is called the "Suggestion" API. While it is possible for it to sometimes functionally work in a manner *like* autocomplete, the intended purpose for it is to find text/documents whose search aware fields match the term you entered.

You can find more details about the API here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/suggestions

Fundamentally, the reason you see other **suggestions** besides the exact match for your query ("HF - Heart failure") in the top hits above the document you wanted to see, is because there are other documents for which your query term is more relevant.

Currently, Azure search does not have an autocomplete feature. Please keep an eye out for our [blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/tag/azure-search/)  and our [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/) for announcements on things we are releasing.

Comment: hello, sir  :-) there is any other way and modification in Suggest API to get exact search like I am doing ?

Comment: So currently as I said there isn't a clear cut way to achieve what you want. However, I recommend you to reach out to azuresearch_contact@microsoft.com with a link to this SO post so that one of our team members can help solve your particular scenario.